# Performing Bagging with the Lasso

Tags: r, glmnet, bagging

I asked this question at StackOverflow but I think it might be better suited for here because I'm hoping to understand the general idea of bagging.

I'm trying to implement bagging in `R` but am having a hard time performing this task with my own function. From my understanding, bagging is essentially taking the average result from `B` bootstrap estimates. I know `caret` has a method for performing bagging, mostly with `CART` methods, but it seems unclear how to implement a function personally developed such as the example below.

```
library(glmnet)
library(boot)

boot_fn <- function(data,index){ #index is the bootstrap sample index
  x <- data[index,1:10]
  y <- data[index,11]
  cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,nfolds=10) #alpha=1, lasso
  bestlam <- cv.out$lambda.min #the best lambda chosen by CV
  lasso.mod <- glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=bestlam)
  coef <- as.vector(coef(lasso.mod))
  return(coef)
}
```

From my understanding of bagging, I believe it would be possible to perform the bootstrap using the `boot` package and averaging the results from the bootstrap estimate dataframe.

```
set.seed(1)
matrix <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol=10)
bootstrap <- boot(matrix, boot_fn,R=50)

### Bagging
coef_matrix <- bootstrap$t0
colMeans(x = coef_matrix, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In general, I'm trying to understand if this is an accurate technique for bagging? Am I correct in taking the average from all bootstrap estimates to determine my prediction model?

Alternatively, is there a better method for implementing a personal function to perform bagging? I've tried using `caret` but it's not clear to me how to input my function and feels cumbersome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bagging requires you average predictions.  I don't see you doing that.  For each bootstrap resample of the data: I) Fit a new glmnet model to that data, II) Take the data you wish to predict on and make each model in the bag predict on that data, III) Average the predictions from each model together.  If you are predicting on 30 new observations with 100 models, then you would average the 100 predictions for each of the 30 observations to obtain 30 averages.

Comment: Doesn't the `boot_fn` provide the predicted coefficients? I might be misunderstanding but do you mean that the function needs to use `predict`? From my understanding, `boot_fn` provides coefficient estimates from the lasso model, which would then be applied for prediction.

Comment: Hmm, actually you might be alright.  If the algebra in my head is correct, the average of the predictions is the inner product between the feature vector and the average coefficients (this is due to the model being linear in the parameters).

Comment: If that's the case, is this the right way to perform bagging? It seems like a crude way to accomplish this task, is there a better or reproducible method with another package?

Comment: Crude, yes.  Other implementations may be more efficient and less error prone.  Sklearn in python has a bagging estimator you might be interested in.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I was hoping for a package in `R` at this point in time.